# Select Dropbox index based on predefined string

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I have a dropbox with a fixed number of items, defined as:

"A --- item 1"

"B --- item 2"

"C --- item 3"

From elsewhere in the program I get a string, containing the first letter of the items. e.g. B
When the form with the dropbox loads, I want to preselect the index with that letter.

I thought about using InStr, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
With Frm
Dim TmpStr as String = String.Empty
TmpStr = Str.InStr(0,1)

Select Case TmpStr
 Case "A"
   cbox.SelectedValue = 0
 Case "B"
   cbox.SelectedValue = 1
 Case "C"
   cbox.SelectedValue = 2
End Case
End With
```

Comment: You're looking for `SelectedIndex`, not `SelectedValue`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the character you can use `TmpStr = Str.Substring(0,1)` to get a single character in string format or `TmpStr = Str.First()` which returns the first letter as a character type.

Then, as mentioned in my comment, inside your select, set the `SelectedIndex` property of your Combobox to the respective index.

Note: You also need to change the `End Case` to `End Select`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a hard-coded `Select Case`, look for a match using a `For Loop` like this:

```
Dim Str As String = "B"
With Frm
    For i As Integer = 0 To cbox.Items.Count - 1
        If cbox.Items(i).ToString.ToUpper.StartsWith(Str.ToUpper) Then
            cbox.SelectedIndex = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End With
```